# PostGIS Unknown Coordinates Format

Tags: postgis, coordinates, well-known-text

I've turned a shapefile into a postgis table using shp2pgsql-gui.

Then, i wanted to get the coordinates of geom column, for that i converted geom to WTK throught ST_AsText(geom) function.

The problem is, the coordinates format is unknown for me :

-69674.5303999996,-294276.2939

Anyone?

Comment: You'll need to provide the SRID or .prj contents before we could tell you what projection that might be (it could be ***any*** projected coordinate system)

Comment: using prj2epsg.org, result are: 3763 - ETRS_1989_TM06-Portugal

Comment: The coordinates are X and Y meters in a local Portugal projection.  If you want something different, you'll need to reproject.

Comment: what you mean with 'reprojet' ?

Comment: ST_Transform, from one coordinate reference system to another.

Comment: Joao, if you want to see longitude/latitude values, do this: `ST_Transform(geom, 4326)`, that will convert your projected coordinates to WGS84 (i.e. 4326) decimal degrees, assuming PostGIS recognizes your projection (EPSG 3763). If your projection is unrecognized, it'll give you dodgy results.

Answer (score 2):

First, when you load the data using shp2gpsql-gui, ensure that you've set the SRID on the data correctly: you have determined your data are EPSG:3763, so use that number in the SRID field of the GUI.

Now that your data is correctly loaded, you can get back geographic coordinate by using the `ST_Transform` function to convert them from their local system into a longitude/latitude system, like

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(geom, 4326)) FROM mytable
```

(4326 is the most common EPSG number used for geographic coordinates, and it's probably what you want for everyday use.)

As a side note, we can confirm that your SRID number guess is correct by running a quick transformation using your example coordinates:

```
select st_astext(
  st_transform(
    st_setsrid(
      st_makepoint(-69674.5303999996,-294276.2939),
    3763),
  4326));

POINT(-8.91600862367417 37.0146103059524)
```

Looks like it's in Portugal, so great!