# ST_AsGeoJSON providing unexpected values

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

GIS newbie here! I have been playing around with the import I did from an OSM region ([that I got from here](https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html)) to postgres using the `osm2pgsql` conversion tool. The command I used to import was this:

`osm2pgsql -c -d gis --slim --style default.style -C 10240 --flat-nodes ./bayern-latest-pgsql bayern-latest.osm.pbf`

Now, everything seems to have worked and I got all the data I want, except for the geometry. When I run a query like this:

`> select osm_id, ST_AsGeoJSON(way), name, from planet_osm_point;`

I get back values like `{"type":"Point","coordinates":[1197606.06200162,6136808.52532997]}` in the `st_asgeojson` column. These coordinates are not what I expected (lat, lon). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's almost certainly because your data is not in a lat/long projection. Trying to find a dupe target; I'm sure there must be one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostGIS Unknown Coordinates Format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202116/postgis-unknown-coordinates-format)

Comment: @jpmc26 Now that you mentioned it, I just discovered the `--latlong` flag on the `osm2pgsql` tool (which I didn't use), perhaps that's the reason?

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm pretty sure that was it. I looked back on the output from the initial import and saw

`Using projection SRS 3857 (Spherical Mercator)`

Output after `--latlong` is:

`Using projection SRS 4326 (Latlong)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong projection when importing the OSM data into Postgres. By default the projection in `SRS 3857 (Spherical Mercator)`, but by passing `--latlong` to `osm2pgsql` it uses the expected projection `SRS 4326 (Latlong)`.